# Need help changing my for loop into a while loop

Tags: java, loops

The current output of my code works, but I want to change the last for loop into a while loop because its more general

Heres my code

```
public class BuildLinkedList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create a linked list that holds 1, 2, ..., 10
    // by starting at 10 and adding each node at head of list

    LinearNode<Integer> head = null;    //create empty linked list
    LinearNode<Integer> intNode;

    for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        // create a new node for i
        intNode = new LinearNode<Integer>(new Integer(i));
        // add it at the head of the linked list
        intNode.setNext(head);
        head = intNode;
    }

    // traverse list and display each data item
    // current will point to each successive node, starting at the first node

    LinearNode<Integer> current = head; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(current.getElement());
        current = current.getNext();
    }
}
```

}

The out put is just a list of numbers that prints 1-10, I want the output to be the same but I'm not sure how to change the bottom for loop, into a while loop without changing my output
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want your code to be "more general" in this case? For loops are perfectly ok when there's a defined range through which you will iterate.

Comment: Replacing a `for` loop with a `while` loop will only decrease readability here. People are very familiar with the idiom you're using, so straying from it will only make people have to look closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your Linked List is not a Circularly Linked List, when you call `getNext()` on the last node it's going to return `null`.

```
LinearNode<Integer> current = head;

while(current != null)
{
    System.out.println(current.getElement());
    current = current.getNext();
}
```

This way you will also avoid `NullPointerException` if your list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

changing for loop into while loop.

```
    int i = 1;
    while(i <= 10)
    {
      System.out.println(current.getElement());
      current = current.getNext();
      i++;
    }
```